# Difference between messages : 'server returning 404' AND 'No route found for GET /routeName

Tags: symfony

windows 8. symfony 2.7  installed with default settings on d:\htdocs\sym\again\blog\

- With apache, running the URL: http://localhost/sym/again/blog/web/hello , returns the following error:

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>   The server returned a "404 Not Found".
>   Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error...

INFO: The above error is different from regular apache 404 'object not found' message. for http://localhost/NonExistingPage

With the built in PHP server `php app/console server:run`,

- running the URL http://localhost:8000/NonExistingRoute returns

> No route found for "GET /NonExistingRoute" 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException 1 linked Exception:    ResourceNotFoundException »

- while running the URL http://localhost:8000/hello, returns the actual page.

  Question: What is the different between the errors ? My understanding:

  1. the regular apache error is simply when a file is requested that is not found by apache
  2. The 'Oops! An Error Occurred The server returned a "404 Not Found". Something is broken' is what is confusing me, I don't understand why/how it is different from the route not found errors.
  3. the route not found means that it reached symfony but did not find any route matching /NonExistingRoute in the routes file.

Another Strange thing:

if routing.yml is changed to:

```
offtopic_books_homepage:
path:     /sym/again/blog/web/hello
defaults: { _controller: OfftopicBooksBundle:Default:index }
```

then

`http://localhost:8000/sym/again/blog/web/hello` - returns the expected page. (with app/console running)
Whereas 
`http://localhost/sym/again/blog/web/hello` - gives the following error:

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>   The server returned a "404 Not Found".

Why ?

Comment: Because first error comes from production environment, second from dev. You second strange thing: you set new route but not clear prod cache, that's why you see it in dev, but not in prod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case please reset cache for `prod` env:

```
php app/console c:c -e prod
```

**Note:**
Please use `dev` env and `app_dev.php` for development, not production environment.

Comment: yeah. thats what I figured out thanks to malcolm's comment. the app/console by default loads into dev environment (it seems) and running through the apache setup loaded the prod environment.
My solution to shift to app_dev : change app.php to app_dev in web/.htaccess